# Using Tkinter to iterate through a list of questions, and use radio buttons to record the answers

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I'm using python to create a tkinter GUI to ask a list of questions (stored in excel), and plan to save the results of the selected buttons within a .csv to ingest into a PBI dashboard. However, I'm having difficulty with two things 1) iterating through the list of questions, and 2) creating a "next" button to navigate to the next question (linked to my first problem). I'm newer to python/Tkinter, so any advice/suggestions are appreciated.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
global root1
global response
#initiate the main window
root1 = Tk()
#create main window label
label1=Label(root1,text="Question Tool")
#define exit button
def Exit():
    root1.destroy()
#define get value
def selection():
    selection=print("User Selected  " + str(response.get()))
#read governance questions
wb=Workbook()
wb=load_workbook('Questions.xlsx')
ws=wb.active
questions=ws['A']
#def start and stop buttons
def Start_Button():
    global response
    root1.destroy()
    root=Tk()
    root.title("Question Tool")
    tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab4 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab5 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tabControl.add(tab1, text ='1) Governance')
    tabControl.add(tab2, text ='2) Eligibility')
    tabControl.add(tab3, text ='3) Operations')
    tabControl.add(tab4, text ='4) Monitoring')
    tabControl.add(tab5, text ='5) Continuing Improvment')
    tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")
    #apply the questions as labels
    ttk.Label(tab1,text=questions[10].value).grid(column = 0,row = 0,padx = 30,pady = 30)
    response=StringVar()
    RB1=ttk.Radiobutton(tab1,text="Yes",value="YES",variable=response)
    RB1.grid(column=0,row=5,padx=10,pady=10)
    RB2=ttk.Radiobutton(tab1,text="No",value="NO",variable=response)
    RB2.grid(column=0,row=10,padx=10,pady=10)
    x=response.get()
    ttk.Button(tab1,text="Next",command=selection).grid(column=0,row=20,padx=10,pady=10)
    ttk.Label(tab2,text ="Eligibility radio buttons/questions here").grid(column = 0,row = 0,padx = 30,pady = 30)
    ttk.Label(tab3,text ="Operations radio buttons/questions here").grid(column = 0,row = 0,padx = 30,pady = 30)
    ttk.Label(tab4,text ="Monitoring radio buttons/questions here").grid(column = 0,row = 0,padx = 30,pady = 30)
    ttk.Label(tab5,text ="Continuing Improvment radio buttons/questions here").grid(column = 0,row = 0,padx = 30,pady = 30)
    root.mainloop()
#add the lable to the root window
label1.pack()
#Add start and stop buttons
Start_Button=Button(root1,text="Click to Begin",padx=10,pady=10, command=Start_Button)
Start_Button.pack()
Exit_Button=Button(root1,text="Exit",padx=10,pady=10,command=Exit)
Exit_Button.pack()
#call main loop
root1.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the questions? Do you want the next question to appear in the label when you click the `Next` button?

Comment: Exactly - I'd like to select the next button and the next question appear in the label.

Comment: Questions, is this a Python list with strings? If "A" is the entire column in which the questions are not sorted, you need to divide them by topic first (tab). But I can show you a possible code for the tkinter and label part of the problem.

Comment: The questions will be stored in different .xlsx workbooks - so these questions will only apply to the first tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the [text or other standard options](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tkinter.Label) of the label after creating this label.

In this example, I am manipulating the value of the variable associated with the buttons (response).
[Radiobuttons](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tkinter.Radiobutton) also have commands like `select()` and `deselect()`.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
# from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
# from openpyxl import load_workbook


# initiate variables
global root1
global response
# answers to be saved somewhere
answers = {"governance": [],
           "eligibility": [],
           "operations": [],
           "monitoring": [],
           "continuing_improvement": []
           }
# prepared question lists
questions = {"governance": ['A', 'B'],
             "eligibility": ['C', 'D'],
             "operations": ['E', 'F'],
             "monitoring": ['G', 'H'],
             "continuing_improvement": ['I', 'J']
             }

# initiate the main window
root1 = Tk()
# create main window label
label1 = Label(root1, text="Question Tool")
# add the lable to the root window
label1.pack()


# define exit button
def Exit():
    root1.destroy()


def selection(parent, label_obj):
    global response
    global questions
    global answers
    user_choice = response.get()
    if user_choice == "":
        # do something if no answer is selected
        print("No answer selected!")
    else:
        print("User Selected:  " + label_obj["text"])
        print("User Selected:  " + user_choice)
        # get question category
        label_obj_name = label_obj.winfo_name()
        # update answers
        answers[label_obj_name].append({label_obj["text"]: user_choice})
        # check if we have run out of questions
        if len(answers[label_obj_name]) == len(questions[label_obj_name]):
            # clear parent tab
            for i in parent.winfo_children():
                i.destroy()
            msg = ttk.Label(parent, text="Done")
            msg.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=30)
            print(answers[label_obj_name])
            print(answers)
            # optional: reset response for new tab
            response.set("")
        else:
            # iterating through the list of questions
            # The questions must be different or not repeated in the same category.
            # get the next question in the list
            next_question = questions[label_obj_name][len(answers[label_obj_name])]
            # get next question text
            label_obj["text"] = next_question
            # optional: reset response for next question
            response.set("")
            # or set default selection
            # response.set("YES")


def create_labels_and_buttons(parent, label_text, label_name):
    """Create a separate label and buttons for each tab.

    The response object is global to all tabs.
    Added a label name to distinguish which category the question belongs to.
    """
    global response
    lb = ttk.Label(parent, text=label_text, name=label_name)
    lb.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=30)
    rb1 = ttk.Radiobutton(parent, text="Yes", value="YES", variable=response)
    rb1.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=10, pady=10)
    rb2 = ttk.Radiobutton(parent, text="No", value="NO", variable=response)
    rb2.grid(column=0, row=10, padx=10, pady=10)
    # you can pass the arguments to the function like here
    ttk.Button(parent, text="Next",
               command=lambda: selection(parent, lb)).grid(column=0, row=20, padx=10, pady=10)
    

def Start_Button():
    global response
    global questions
    global answers
    root1.destroy()
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Question Tool")
    tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab4 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab5 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tabControl.add(tab1, text='1) Governance')
    tabControl.add(tab2, text='2) Eligibility')
    tabControl.add(tab3, text='3) Operations')
    tabControl.add(tab4, text='4) Monitoring')
    tabControl.add(tab5, text='5) Continuing Improvement')
    tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    # response for buttons
    response = StringVar()
    # apply the questions as labels
    create_labels_and_buttons(parent=tab1, label_text=questions["governance"][0], label_name="governance")
    create_labels_and_buttons(parent=tab2, label_text=questions["eligibility"][0], label_name="eligibility")
    create_labels_and_buttons(parent=tab3, label_text=questions["operations"][0], label_name="operations")
    create_labels_and_buttons(parent=tab4, label_text=questions["monitoring"][0], label_name="monitoring")
    create_labels_and_buttons(parent=tab5, label_text=questions["continuing_improvement"][0],
                              label_name="continuing_improvement")

    root.mainloop()


# add start and stop buttons
Start_Button = Button(root1, text="Click to Begin", padx=10, pady=10, command=Start_Button)
Start_Button.pack()
Exit_Button = Button(root1, text="Exit", padx=10, pady=10, command=Exit)
Exit_Button.pack()
# call main loop
root1.mainloop()
```